# MultivaluedMap in RESTEasy and square brackets

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm building something of a relay server, using JAX-RS. I need to be able to extract any query parameters from a GET request and then re-wrap them into another request, to pass along to another server. I'm unfamiliar with `MultivaluedMap`, but I just figured out what is happening. The `UriInfo` class's `getQueryParameters` method returns a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`. What bit me, unexpectedly, is that the values of each parameter are `List` values, even though they purport to be `String` values (by the way I read the JavaDoc).

In other words, if I have a key-value pair of `foo=bar`, in the URL query string, when I extract the parameter, it comes out as `foo=[bar]`. This totally throws me for a loop (a 500 Server Error, actually) when I try to re-wrap the parameter and send it along to the other server.

Is there another way to handle unpacking the query string from a Request, and then re-packing it for another Request? I'm including some code to illustrate my issue:

```
@GET
@Path("parameters")
public Response showParameters(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    
    sb.append("<h4>Parameters:</h4>");
    if (parameters != null) {
        sb.append("<ul>");
        Iterator it = parameters.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String)it.next();
            sb.append("<li>")
                .append(key)
                .append(": ")
                .append(parameters.get(key))
                .append("</li>");
        }
        sb.append("</ul>");
    }
    else {
        sb.append("<p>None</p>");   
    }
    
    return Response.ok(sb.toString()).build();
}
```

So, in summary, what gets printed out from the code above, if the request has query parameters, is something like this:

**Parameters:**

- key1: [value1]
- key2: [value2]
- key3: [value3]

Is there another way to unpack/re-pack, and maybe avoid this whole issue altogether? Thanks.

### Complete answer

@Jack deserves credit for pointing me in the right direction, and I am marking [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833458/155167) as correct, but here is what I got working.

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    
    // Assume instance variable providing URI (without query string).
    WebTarget target = client.target(theRequestUri);
    
    // Instance variable uriInfo.
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    
    if (parameters != null && parameters.size() > 0) {
        Iterator it = parameters.keySet().iterator();
        String key = null;
        StringTokenizer st = null;
        
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            key = (String)it.next();
            
            // RESTEasy API is quirky, here. It wraps the values in square 
            // brackets; moreover, each value is separated by a comma and  
            // padded by a space as well. ([one, two, three, etc])
            
            st = new StringTokenizer(parameters.get(key).toString(), "[,]");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                target = target.queryParam(key, st.nextToken().trim());
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Instance method: getContentType.
    Response response = target.request().accept(getContentType()).get();
```

Comment: How are you making the other request? When calling using WebResource (jersey) it accepts MultivaluedMap as query params using `queryParams(map)`. Perhaps If you post your other request details, it will clarify

Comment: I'm looking through the Javadocs (and the book I have from Bill Burke), and, as of yet, I don't see anything like that for the RESTEasy implementation.

Comment: In RESTEasy, WebTarget has a similar method to what you mention, but its signature looks like this: queryParam(String name, Object... values). That's not all that helpful. Call me crazy, but I'm thinking that one part of an API ought to be integrated with another part. It doesn't help to pull out a MultivalueMap<String,String> but then have the above signature method should you want to put the same values back in somewhere. I'm hoping that there is something I'm missing.

Comment: P.S. Maybe I am crazy. I'm reviewing the syntax for variable argument lengths for methods right now. I've never used them, but I'm finding in the Java documentation the following: "[values may be] passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments."

Comment: Instead of parsing the string:
uriInfo.getQueryParameters().forEach((k, v)->v.forEach((s)-> target.queryParam(k,s)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of MultivaluedMap interface.

```java
public interface MultivaluedMap<K, V> extends Map<K, List<V>> {
```

It returns the values as `List`. 
Instead of `parameters.get(key)` try `parameters.getFirst(key)`

Note that this will drop the other values for the same parameter. It is possible to send multiple values for same parameter while making a rest call such as `blahblah:8080?foo=bar1&foo=bar2`. With `getFirst()` call you will get `bar1` value only. If you are sure you will not get multiple calls, you can go with `getFirst(key)` approach

--- **UPDATED** ---
Based on your comments, it seems you need to iterate over the multivalued map and call queryParam on the WebTarget instance. I understand you are looking for a library/straight forward way to do this. I did not try RESTEasy. But code I believe should be simple enough.

```
multiValuesMap?.each { key, values->
 webTargetInstance = webTargetInstance.queryParam(key, values as Object[])
}
```

Comment: I worry that I can't rely on having only single values. I'm thinking there must be an easy way -- meaning, a "magical" library/API way -- of doing it, where the queries can be taken from the incoming request and then wrapped up in a new outgoing request. As of yet, though, I haven't managed to find it. (I'm still looking.) Thanks.

Comment: I took your advice. FYI, this is what the RESTEasy API does to the query string: EndDate=[2014-07-18 00:00:00]&StartDate=[2005-01-01 00:00:00]&FirmID=[9001]. Do you see the square brackets? It's a disaster. Moreover, the API doesn't say what it does about encoding/decoding, as it's packing/unpacking a query string. (For the record, it seems to encode-decode properly.) Anyway, I can take it from here, but I just wanted to share what a cluster f%@# it is. (P.S. I used a proprietary encoding just then, for the sake of propriety.)

Comment: I gave you the credit, but edited my question to provide a working answer.